# Rating a wiki page in edit mode will raise “save conflict error”

Tags: development, publishing-site, publishing-page, library, wiki

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside SharePoint 2013 , I have enabled page rating, but I find a problem, as follow:-

1. User create/edit a wiki page.
2. While on edit mode the user  Rate the page (by clicking on the rating starts)
3. Save the page

The problem is that the user will receive the following error:-

[image]

So can anyone advice what is the recommended approach to overcome this issue ? is disable rating on edit mode an approach that can be achieved ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there would be a way around. Because it seems that they have intentionally kept this feature and hence provided the `Save Conflict` popup to deal with the situation.

**Update :**

Using `Page Layout` you can hide it as follows.

Wrap

```
<b>
                    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:cms,enterwiki_pagerating%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></b>
                    <div>
                        <SharePointPortalControls:AverageRatingFieldControl FieldName="5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742" runat="server"/></div>
```

within following

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel class="ewiki-margin" PageDisplayMode="Display" runat="server">

</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Comment: but can i hide the rating section in edit mode from the page layout ?

Comment: I haven't tried this but since you can always modify the Page Layout using SharePoint Designer 2013. It seems possible (at least theoretically).

Comment: seems i can not add "ControlMode:Display" for the <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:cms,enterwiki_pagerating%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></b>

Comment: Check out my update. It worked for me.

Comment: yes it partially worked. I need to wrap only the following "<b>
     <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:cms,enterwiki_pagerating%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></b>
     <div>
      <SharePointPortalControls:AverageRatingFieldControl FieldName="5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742" runat="server"/></div>" . because if i wrap the whole <div class="ewiki-slink"> then some managed metadata fields will became unavailable in edit mode also..

Comment: I was having `Page Rating` and `Categories`. And, i didn't needed both :-). Hence, i wrapped it completely.

Comment: so that other people do not get confused thinking that they will always get "Save conflict " error..thanks